# How to render multiple nested array objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get an array from the server containing arrays that contain objects:
[Arrays with objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh6jo.png)

This is information about 2 buildings. There are 2 buildings, the first building has 2 floors, the first floor has several rooms, the second floor has 2 wings, each of which has a few rooms inside. In the second building there are just a few rooms. As a layout, it looks like this:
[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjCZE.png)

I want to render this array with objects in the form of such a tree. I managed to render it to this state: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2OGW.png). Next, I need to render the most nested components, but I encountered a problem. 
This is my component file:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

 class Tree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    buildings: [],
    rooms: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  var buildings = new Scorocode.Query("buildings");
    buildings.find().then((finded) => {
    let buildings = finded.result;
    this.setState({buildings: buildings});
    buildings.map(buildings => (
      this.setState({rooms: buildings.rooms})
    ))
    console.info(buildings);
  });
}

render() {
 return (
   <div id="multi-derevo">
    <h4><a href="#">Начальная схема</a></h4>
    <ul>
      {this.state.buildings.map(buildings => (
        <li key={this.state.buildings.name}><span><a>{buildings.name}</a></span>
          <ul>
            {buildings.rooms.map((room, name) => (
              <li key={buildings.rooms.name}><span><a>{room.name}</a></span>
                <ul>
                  {rooms.children.map((child, name) => (
                    <li key={rooms.children.name}><span><a>{child.name}</a></span></li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
   </div>
 );
}
}
export default Tree;
```

I get an error "rooms is not defined" for the most nested component. As I understand, I need to add it to state and I do it wrong here:

```
 buildings.map(buildings => (
  this.setState({rooms: buildings.rooms})
))
```

I am newbie in React, so don't judge me strictly, please. I'm trying to find the solution for hours and still can't solve this problem.

Comment: Just clarifying I see you set your `map` to be `(entity, name) =>` and wanted to make sure `name` wasn't being confused as something else because [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes an `index` into that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work? Have not tested it though

```
class Tree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      areas: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var areas = new Scorocode.Query("buildings");
    this.setState({ areas })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.parent && <span>{this.props.parent.name}</span>}
        {this.state.areas.map((area, i) => {
          <li key={i}><Tree parent={area} /></li>
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
export Tree;
```